# messed up my /user directory permissions an now cannot run sudo or gksu

Tags: command-line, sudo, gksudo

while changing the permissions for the /usr folder
of owner to root read and write
of group to root read and write
of other to read and write  i ignoratly checked to 
box to propagate to all contained directories/files

now I cannot run sudo or gksu,  how can i fix this?
the error message when trying to run sudo on a command is:

sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so must be only be writable by owner
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins

help!

Comment: Backup your home directory if you have anything important, and reinstall.

Comment: You can preserve your data in /home with a reinstall, have been able to do so for years. " Since Hardy it is possible to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the content of the /home folder (the folder that contains program settings, internet bookmarks, emails and all your documents, music, videos and other user files). This can be done even if /home is not on a separate partition " https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Answer (score -1):

Boot a Live CD/USB or any other linux distro and change the permission back to what they should be.

See, no need to reinstall.

Comment: I have tried using ubuntu 14.04 live cd and of course it will not work becuase the drive will not be shown in a form that will allow the usr folder to be seeen,  instead you can only see what appears to be the boot directory contents

Comment: i tried this, the drive does not show up

Comment: I finally used ubuntu mate  15.04 desktop amd64 and was able to both see the drive and change the permissions using caja.